# Surefire is triggering jacoco, and that want a minimum coverage. I need to disable that for now

Tags: maven, jacoco, maven-surefire-plugin

I need to disable jacoco for checking for a minimum code coverage amount. Simple reason is that we are just beginning to write unit tests now, retroactively. We can't just not ship because a product which currently works, can't pass some tests. We need to add these tests over time, or severely reduce the minimum.

How do I either disable jacoco, or lower the minimum to 0?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you use `jacoco-maven-plugin`, so please read its documentation - http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html

In particular [page about `check` goal](http://www.jacoco.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/check-mojo.html) that performs checking. On this page you can find how to configure it and that it has `skip` parameter.